# Mongoose Model Not Registered when Executing Unit Tests with Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose

Here is the error Im struggling with:
[image: Uncaught Type Error]

My bookIntegrationTests.js looks like this:

[image: bookIntegrationTests.js]

My app.js is as follows:

[image: app.js]

Finally bookModel.js is:

[image]

My bad @Brian, Here's the POST Request:

[image]

and the controller containing the actual POST function:

[image]

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Include the actual route that handles the POST request for books

Comment: Take another look.

Comment: I replicated your project and the routes and tests seem to work. My guess would be that bookController.post is not accessible by the router configuration. I would try running the project without the mocha test and use a tool like Postman for testing your rest api.